# Render html in Angular Material Table cell

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-material2, angular-material-table

I am trying to add html content in angular material but the tags show as simple text in html
for example "first line `<br>` .here should be a new line"
How do I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML` attribute binding

```
<td mat-cell 
  *matCellDef="let element"
  [innerHTML]="element.name">
</td>
```

**TS**

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {
    position: 1,
    name: '<b>Hydrogen</b> <br>Test', 
    ...
  },
  ...
];
```

**Output**

| Position | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **Hydrogen** Test |

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aybhvk)

Comment: You can use [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description) directive on `td` directive, like `[ngClass]="{'my-custom-class': element.name === 'something'}"`

Comment: @Anna sorry I don't get you completely

Comment: @Anna it would be great if you could open a new question, so that more people can be involved in the discussion, you may get varieties of approaches/solutions.

Comment: @Anna what's this now `obj.p343?.[0]?.koddf`?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please explain with example. I'm unclear on what exactly you need

Comment: I got a bit, I don't get meaning of "*while I want it to do it only when it's mapped from shares*" what is mapped from shares?

Comment: You need some expression or condition that has to be satisfied with `ngClass` to work. I think you are a better person to decide that condition, as you know more about your project. 

Still from what I understood, I can guess `[ngClass]="{'my-custom-class': element.points === shares}` should work. This will only points object contains `shares` reference

Comment: yes, then only it apply CSS, that's right? using `[ngClass]="{'my-custom-class': element.points === shares}`

Comment: I applied the ngclass with a condition on another property of element that had const value, thanks a lot

Comment: @Anna great to know, you were able to solve the problem. Happy Coding! :)